# Time input field in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I need to implement a `TimeEdit`(HH:MM:SS) field in QML similar to `QTimeEdit` in QT C++. In QML I didn't find TimeEdit and I have implemented the control similar to TimeEdit using `TextField` and if I add **inputMask** then the **Regular expression** is not at all validated, Is there any way that I can achieve this? Following is the code.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Time Edit")

    TextField{
        id:textEditTD
        text : ""
        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly

        inputMask: "dd:dd:dd; "
        validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$ / }

        width:100
        height:50
        background:Rectangle{
            color:"transparent"
            border.color: "red"
            border.width:2
            radius:(width * 0.05)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe whitespace at the very end of RegExp is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two ways to implement this :

1) I made changes to **Orient** answer to meet my requirement and following is the change which works when `backspace` is pressed:

```
virtual
State validate(QString & input, int & pos) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
{
    const QStringList parts = input.split(":");
    if (parts.length() != 3) {
        input = QStringLiteral("00:00:00");
    }
    else
    {
        int hours = 0;
        int minutes = 0;
        int seconds = 0;

        //hours
        if(parts[0].toInt() > 23){
            hours = 23;
            pos +=1; //Increment the position
        }
        else{
            QString str = parts[0];
            if(str.contains(" ")){
                str.replace(" ","0");
            }
            hours = str.toInt();
        }

        // Minutes
        if(parts[1].toInt() > 59){
            minutes = 59;
            pos +=1; //Increment the position
        }
        else{
            QString str = parts[1];
            if(str.contains(" ")){
                str.replace(" ","0");
            }
            minutes = str.toInt();
        }

        //Seconds
        if(parts[2].toInt() > 59){
            seconds = 59;
            pos +=1; //Increment the position
        }
        else{
            QString str = parts[2];
            if(str.contains(" ")){
                str.replace(" ","0");
            }
            seconds = str.toInt();
        }

        const QTime time{hours, minutes,seconds};
        Q_ASSERT(time.isValid());
        input = time.toString("hh:mm:ss");
    }
    return Acceptable;
}
```

2) By just changing the `inputMask` and `RegExp` which is very easy:

```
inputMask: "99:99:99"       
       validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /^([0-1\s]?[0-9\s]|2[0-3\s]):([0-5\s][0-9\s]):([0-5\s][0-9\s])$ / }
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following combination of "round-down" `QValidator`-derived custom validator of time input (it is simple to add seconds filed):

```
#pragma once

#include <QTime>
#include <QValidator>

// almost equiv to RegExpValidator { regExp: /(([01][0-9])|(2[0-3])):([0-5][0-9])/ }
class TimeValidator
        : public QValidator
{

    Q_OBJECT

public :

    explicit TimeValidator(QObject * const parent = Q_NULLPTR)
        : QValidator{parent}
    { ; }

    virtual
    State validate(QString & input, int & pos) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        Q_UNUSED(pos);
        const auto parts = input.splitRef(':');
        if (parts.length() != 2) {
            input = QStringLiteral("00:00");
        } else {
            const int hours = qBound(0, parts.first().toInt(), 23);
            const int minutes = qBound(0, parts.last().toInt(), 59);
            const QTime time{hours, minutes};
            Q_ASSERT(time.isValid());
            input = time.toString("hh:mm");
        }
        return Acceptable;
    }

};

template< typename T >
int qmlRegisterClass(int versionMajor = 1, int versionMinor = 0)
{
    const auto className = T::staticMetaObject.className();
    return ::qmlRegisterType< T >(className, versionMajor, versionMinor, className);
}

// ...

qmlRegisterClass< TimeValidator >();
```

And `TextFiled` with `inputMask`:

```
import TimeValidator 1.0

TextField {
    id: timePicker

    verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter
    horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter

    text: "00:00"
    inputMask: "00:00;_"

    validator: TimeValidator {}

    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly

    // placeholderText: "00:00" // for implicitWidth
    // Layout.minimumWidth: implicitWidth
    // Layout.fillWidth: true
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but there is a problem when `backspace` key is used for example:  if i enter `12:30` and later if `backspace` is clicked the value becomes `01:03` but it should become `00:00` can you please suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: @pra7 there is `pos` modifiable parameter. You can make more complex logic changing it.

Comment: @pra7 anyways input is verified and always acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ... I have made changes to meet my requirements.